# Url not loading inside a iframe in Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, safari

I have a iframe in my asp webpage and I'm dynamically loading a url from code behind.
But during the loading of my url in the iframe it is not opening in Chrome and safari.
It is working perfectly in IE and FF.

Can any one please help me to solve this problem. Sample code is given below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="a.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Title_a" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <iframe id="ifrm" src="http://www.sample.com/" runat="server"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Admin_Title_a : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to use `runat="server"` as an `iframe` tag attribute. Also try setting some width and height to the `iframe`. Try this

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="http://www.sample.com/" height="300px" width="600px">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframe tag.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: I am curious, is there really a browser left in use that don't support iframes :)?

Comment: @YvesR: curiousity is a good thing. read up at leisure http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_browser :)

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to the Page_Load Event

Protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

this.ifrm.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.sample.com/"

}